# how insert mongo data into redis list

Tags: redis, scrapy

Now, my mongodb have a table, in it is the keywords and the number of grabs by keywords are stored, now how to insert the keywords into the redis list and  by the number of grabs priority level?
thks! very much
this is my code:

```
def init_mongo_to_redis(mongo_db, redis_pool):
    r = redis.Redis(connection_pool = redis_pool)
    mongo_handle = mongo_db.keywords_tbl.find({}, {'keyword': 1, 'keyword_type': 1, \
            'ignore_station': 1}, no_cursor_timeout=True)
    redis_len = r.llen('fetch_keywords')
    if redis_len != 0:
        logging.info('redis fetch_keywords size is %d', redis_len)
        return

    logging.info('init redis fetch_keywords start')

    r_pipe = r.pipeline()
    pbar = tqdm(mongo_handle)
    for keyword in pbar:
        item = {
            'keyword_type': keyword['keyword_type'],
            'ignore_station': keyword['ignore_station'],
            'keyword': keyword['keyword']
        }
        r_pipe.lpush('fetch_keywords', json.dumps(item))
        pbar.set_description('Processing %s' % keyword)
    r_pipe.execute()

    logging.info('init redis fetch_keywords end :%d', r.llen('fetch_keywords'))
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have come up with and ask specific issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you have to order by a numerical (integer or float) value in Redis, it is better to consider first using [Sorted Sets](https://redis.io/commands/zadd). You can order values by a score, that in your case I suppose is

> number of grabs priority level